# How to pull from a branch?

Tags: git

The question sounds too trivial. I wished it was. :)

I have recently created an experimental branch called `deals_feature`.
After a day work, I have commited and pushed the changes back to the server.
I even went to the server and did a `git log deals_feature` and I can see the latest commit log message on that branch.

And now back to the pc, I am trying to get the latest on that branch.

I did a `git branch -a` to see make sure I am on the branch:

```
* deals_feature
  master
  remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/master
  remotes/origin/deals_feature
  remotes/origin/master
```

But when I do a `git pull` it seems its pulling from Master instead of the branch.

```
From .
 * branch            master     -> FETCH_HEAD
Already up-to-date.
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Please, show outout of `$ git remote show your_remote_name`, where `your_remote_name` is name of your remote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must specify branch to push using

```
$ git pull origin deals_feature
```

Propably pulling when you are in `deals_feature` branch will work also, but now I don't have time to test it.

Comment: I think you misunderstood the question. Its about pulling not pushing.  But you gave me an idea: `$ git pull origin deals_feature` worked.

Comment: Awww, each. Sorry, it's very early here so my brain haven't started working yet.

Answer (score 1):

Try `git fetch origin` and then do `git diff origin/deals_feature` on your local deals_feature branch. If it outputs nothing then you are on the latest one already.

I always use `git fetch` + `git merge` instead of `git pull` as i see it more flexible when working with multiple remotes and multiple branches.